# Interpolation,data binding, angular javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, drag-and-drop, angular6

This is switch case in this I am sending login form HTML by inner HTML with drag and drop.

```
 case 'form':
       if (this.formbuild) {
       } else {
         this.global_service.showNotification('Form Already Listed',4);
      }
     this.formbuild=true;
     this.buttonPanelSettings = true;
     data = document.createElement('div');
     data.setAttribute('id', 'column1');
     data.setAttribute('class', 'row');
     data.style.height = 'auto';
     data.style.width = 'auto';
     var count = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic_coulmn1").length;
     data.className = "dynamic_coulmn1";
     data.id = "dynamic_coulmn1_" + count;
     // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
       data.innerHTML = '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto"><div class="card card-signin mb-5 mt-5"><div class="card-body text-center"><h2 class="card-title text-center mt-3 mb-4">Login Form</h2><form action="#" id="mainform" method="get" name="mainform"><span id="myForm"></span><p></p><input type="submit" class="btn mt-2 mb-2 btn-info" value="Submit"></form></div></div></div></div></div>';
     this.totalComponents.column1.push({ column1: data.id });
       data.onclick = this.clickCurrentButton.bind(this, count);
break;
```

Below code is an input filed I want to do binding with login form name. which help me change the login form name by the input field

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3" *ngIf="buttonPanelSettings">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text module_font" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Form Name:</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control inside_size" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                         name="fucntion" placeholder="model name">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two way binding technique of angular.
In angular 2+ versions you only need to add ngModel to input like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inside_size" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                     name="fucntion" placeholder="model name" [(ngModel)]="formName">
```

and in your .ts file declare variable like this

```
formName : any;
```

Comment: i have replace the input filed as u have mentioned above but output is not  wrong;     

this login name as i have mentioned above in javascript innerhtml

<div class="card-body text-center"><h2 class="card-title text-center mt-3 mb-4">{{formName}}</h2><form action="#" id="mainform" method="get" name="mainform">

Comment: please correct your comment. i didn't get you. And also please share some screenshot of output if you can

Comment: did you declare this "formName" in your .ts file?

Comment: show me your complete typescript code after declaring formName

Comment: threre is some privacy in my code show i can't show. so can u give some suggestions

Comment: @AbhinavSharma hide that part which you don't want to show. I can't give suggestion until i will see your code.